# How can I find out which wallet belongs to which cryptocoin?

Tags: wallet, alternatives, wallet.dat

I have multiple decrypted wallets in the same folder. How can I find out which wallet belongs to which cryptocoin? All wallets are named wallet_x.dat, so the name gives no hint.

UPDATE:
I have no access to the addresses within the wallet, because I can't import them, because I don't know which client I would need.

Comment: my answer is very similar to nate's: use https://gist.github.com/nlitsme/b3102191c2dc14c587e7,  and look for 'name' in the output

Comment: @WillemHengeveld I'm not familiar with reading python code. Can you explain the theory behind this code?

Comment: @NateEldredge I would like to have an answer, that explains me where exactly I can find the indicator, not just which tool to use to find it.

Comment: what the python code does: read the berkeley db records, and print the records in readable form. And btw, you don't need to be able to read python in order to run it, just type:  `python dumpwallet`

Comment: an even simpler method would be to load wallet.dat in any hexeditor or some other tool to view binaries, and look for the string 'name', directly followed by something which looks like an address.  I think even the unix commandline tool 'strings'  would be sufficient.

Comment: @WillemHengeveld The script is definitely doing what I wanted. Thanks a lot. But I prefer to understand how it works, so I can rewrite it in a language that I understand, because I want to make it fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the wallet address, if it starts with 1 it is a Bitcoin wallet, if it starts with an L it is a litecoin wallet and so on, google to know how to identify the starting of the rest of the crypto wallets (blockchains are the first places to go).

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. To read addresses from the wallet I would have to import it first. But I can't import it, because I don't know which client I need. Therefore I need to identify the type of coin it belongs to, without having access to the addresses within the wallet.

Comment: Then if there is no special app to identify them (which I'm not aware of) you can do two things, either you install all clients and try to open the wallet with each one until you manage to identify your wallets OR you find and read the documentation describing wallet format and you read them and identify them yourself, I don't think wallet format differ so much from one another since almost all crypto currencies are copies of the bitcoin code modified and adapted to some special needs or somthing. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet